# xslt tabs using for-each from xslt variable contain xml

Tags: xslt

I am trying to generate tab interface based on XML in an XSLT variable.

So the XSLT Variable

```
    <xsl:variable name="tabs">
      <tabs>
        <tab name="All" href="ref1" col="AppScript"></tab>
        <tab name="xxx" href="ref2" col="python_docs"></tab>
      </tabs>
    </xsl:variable>
```

My xslt to create the tabs is

```
            <div class="container" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="border-bottom-width: 0px; margin-top: 0px;">    
                    <xsl:for-each select="$tabs">
                        <xsl:if test="PARAM[(@name='site') and (@value='{tabs/tab/@col}')]">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="{tabs/tab/@href}">                                 
                                    <xsl:value-of select="tabs/tab/@name"></xsl:value-of>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <li>
                            <a href="{tabs/tab/@href}">
                                <xsl:value-of select="tabs/tab/@name"></xsl:value-of>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

What i am getting is

```
<li><a href="ref1 ref2">All xxxx</a></li>
```

What I am trying to get is 
when site=python_docs

```
<li class="active"><a href="ref2">xxx</a></li>
<li><a href="ref1">All</a></li>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your xslt to create tabs to

```
    <div class="container" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="border-bottom-width: 0px; margin-top: 0px;">    
            <xsl:for-each select="$tabs/tabs/tab">
                <xsl:if test="PARAM[(@name='site') and (@value='{@col}')]">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="{@href}">                                 
                            <xsl:value-of select="@name"></xsl:value-of>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </xsl:if>
                <li>
                    <a href="{@href}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@name"></xsl:value-of>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I can't seem to get the value of @col though.

Comment: create a variable after `<xsl:for-each select="$tabs/tabs/tab">`. You can use `<xsl:variable name="col" select="@col"/>` and use the variable in comparison.

Comment: I tried,     <xsl:for-each select="$tabs/tabs/tab">
     <xsl:variable name="col" select="@col" />
     <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="PARAM[(@name='site') and (@value='$col')]">. Its not working.

Comment: ∘value='$col'@value='$col' should be `@value=$col`

Comment: maybe you should post your XML as I do not know/see any `PARAM` nodes.

Comment: <GSP VER="3.2">
..
<PARAM name="site" value="python_docs" original_value="python_docs"/>

Comment: I have made a simple XML and a stylesheet in http://xsltransform.net/jyyiVhu. Check it out.